# Issue with this in Jquery 1.10.1

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, onclick

I am working with Jquery 1.10.1 for multiple check box select.

Check the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/HBGzy/68/

It works fine when I use JQuery 1.6.4 but I am using JQuery 1.10.1 I tried different methods but now use:

It works fine in some condition when I use the below code:

```
function Checkboxall(valueclass) {
  alert('#'+valueclass);
    var chk = $('#'+valueclass).is(':checked')?true:false;
    alert(chk);
    $('.chk_boxes1').attr('checked',chk);
  }
```

Like `Onclick=" Checkboxall(chk_boxes)"`

But only once I can use per page load. Can some one help me in solving the issue?

Comment: use .prop() instead of .attr()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is as simple as (please read the documentation for [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to understand the difference between `.attr()` and `.prop()`)

```
$('.chk_boxes').click(function(){
    $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5zuay/)

Comment: Works well with Jquery 1.10.2 / 1.10.1.. Thank you!